# Issue with FileOutputStream and DataOutput Stream

Tags: java, dataoutputstream, filestreams

The problem is when I write a character using `FileOutputStream` it is readable.
But when I chain it with `DataOutputStream` the written data becomes unreadable.

Why is that ? Since both `FileOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` write in bytes to the file.   How exactly will the processing happen ?

Code:

```
File newFile = new File("C:\\Jeevantest.as");
FileOutputStream outFp = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
outFp.write('X');
outFp.close();

In the file Jeevantest.as, the char 'X' can be seen. 

File newFile = new File("C:\\Jeevantest.as");
FileOutputStream outFp = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
DataOutputStream dp = new DataOutputStream(outFp);
dp.writeChar('J');
outFp.close();
```

In this case, the following output is shown:

[image: Output]

Need to understand why ?

Comment: Try closing `dp` instead of `outFp`

Comment: Didn't help. The output remains the same. One follow up question. Will closing the underlying stream effectively close all the chained streams ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference resides not in the `OutputStreams` but in the write methods you are using: they differ. In your first example you use `dp.write()` and in your second example you use `dp.writeChar()`.

Change `dp.writeChar()` to `dp.write()` in your second example and the results will be as expected.

`java.io.DataOutputStream.writeChar(int)` method is implemented as follows:

```
public final void writeChar(int v) throws IOException {
    out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
    out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
    incCount(2);
}
```

See soource code of [`writeChar(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#DataOutputStream.writeChar%28int%29)

while `java.io.DataOutputStream.write(int)` has following implementation:

```
 public synchronized void write(int b) throws IOException {
     out.write(b);
     incCount(1);
 }
```

See soource code of [`write(int)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/io/DataOutputStream.java#DataOutputStream.write%28int%29)

Comment: I know this will work. I want to know why writeChar() or any writeX make the output unreadable.

Comment: @JeevanVarughese In your original question you didn't ask this. I edited my answer to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

writeChar writes char as a 2-byte value in UTF-16 encoding. In case 'J' it is `00 4A`. To display it correctly you need to use correct encoding

Answer (score 1):

`DataOutputStream` is used to store primitive in a portable way.
Look how a char is written to stream

```
public final void writeChar(int v) throws IOException {
  out.write((v >>> 8) & 0xFF);
  out.write((v >>> 0) & 0xFF);
  incCount(2);
}
```

A char is write using 2 bytes, high byte first. Because hi-byte is 0 (in your case 'J' => 004A) the result is what you see in you file.

Answer (score 0):

```
File newFile = new File("C:\\Jeevantest.as");
FileOutputStream outFp = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
DataOutputStream dp = new DataOutputStream(outFp);
dp.writeChars("J");
outFp.close();
dp.close();
```

- First of all writeChar takes int argument so, if you need to pass a string you need to use `writeChars(String arg)`
- Close dp stream.

Answer (score 0):

The stream consists of binary data with nothing to indicate the type of individual values, or where they begin in the stream. 
So it can only be read using a DataInputStream. Check this oracle official tutorial for further information:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html

Answer (score 0):

The stream consists of binary data with nothing to indicate the type of individual values, or where they begin in the stream. 
So it can only be read using a DataInputStream. Check this link for further information
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/datastreams.html